# How to extend mapstruct`s @mapping annotation

Tags: java, mapstruct, annotation-processing

I have a dictionaries which has multiple fields like: `id`, `code`, `ruName`, `enName`. `id` is a UUID, the others are `String`s.

What I want is something like that:

```
@Mapping(source = "sourceName", target = "targetName", dictionary = "dictName", dictionaryField = "dictionaryField")
```

and based on target type it will generate something like that

```
if target type UUID 
    return target.targetName(getId(dictionary ,dictionaryField , sourceName));

if target type String
    return target.targetName(getValue(dictionary, dictionaryField, sourceName));
```

What I have now is a generator which generates mappers for every dictionary and for every field in format `dictionaryByFieldName`, so I can use this format:

```
@Mapping(source="sourceName", target="targetName", qualifiedByName = "dictionaryByFieldName")
```

But I don't like it cos most of created mappers have no uses in project and aren't valid cos not every field is unique to get id by field-_-

Comment: what type of object are dictionary and dictionaryField in this case? And how stable are these values per mapping?
For example: the dictionaryField could be a String and always called the same for the same mapping, while the dictionary is a Dictionary class, which could change depending on the call.

Comment: it`s a record from db which can have any amount of values with any amount of names:) it has 2 main methods getId which return id of first record from "dictionaryName" dictionary by "fieldName" name of one of fields in that dictionary and "fieldValue" value of that field. uuid id = getId(dictionaryName, fieldName, fieldValue); And method which returns value of the field by id of record, name of dictionary and name of field. String fieldValue = getValue(dictionaryName, fieldName, id);

Answer (score 1):

Currently it is not possible to retrieve the fieldname within mapstruct, what however is possible is using an `@Mapping` per field to minimize the amount of mapping code.

for example:

```
    @Mapping( target = "myUuidFieldName", expression = 'java(dict.getId("myUuidFieldName", source.getMyUuidFieldName()))' )
    @Mapping( target = "myStringFieldName", expression = 'java(dict.getValue("myStringFieldName", source.getMyStringFieldName()))' )
    Target map(Source source, @Context Dictionary dict);
```

and have a separate class called `Dictionary` in which you store the mappings for retrieval. This way you can easily replace the `Dictionary` with another `Dictionary` implementation in case you need a different translation.

Example of a `Dictionary` class:

```
private class Dictionary{
    DbRecordAccessor dbRecord;
    Map<String, RetrievalInformation> retrievalMap;
    // constructor and retrievalMap initialization methods

    UUID getId(String fieldName, String value){
        RetrievalInformation info = retrievalMap.get(fieldName);
        return dbRecord.getId(info.getDictionaryName(), fieldName, info.getDictionaryField());
    }

    String getValue(String fieldName, String value){
        RetrievalInformation info = retrievalMap.get(fieldName);
        return dbRecord.getValue(info.getDictionaryName(), fieldName, getId(fieldName, value));
    }
}
```

[The following is not (yet) supported by mapstruct. See here for more information.](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/2688)

It would be nice if you could have done the following:

```
    Target map(Source source, @Context Dictionary dict);

    UUID getId(String value, @TargetProperty String targetField, @Context Dictionary dict) {
        return dict.getId(targetField, value);
    }
```